# pass untruncated string in AJAX parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

I am passing and argument of type string to an AJAX call. The value i am passing reads as `01007` but when i handle the call at server side, it passes `1007`.

Is there a way i can pass the argument as String and get 01007 in the service call? I tried `data:"{someKey:" + passedKey.toString() + "}"` but it didnt work. Here passedKey is 01007.

Argument type in the service call is string.

Comment: toString() converts boolean values, string(passedKey) is what you want.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy what the heck is `string(passedKey)`?? I never saw this in javascript...

Comment: @Christoph: He means `String()`.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: Neither one will make any difference.

Comment: @SLaks well, the difference between `string()` and `String()` is tiny, but yet extremely huge, since the first one will most likey throw a Reference Error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concatenated JSON string reads `{someKey:01007}`.
Do you see the problem?

You should pass an object literal, not a JSON string.
jQuery will then serialize it correctly.